# Is it redundant to start a thread in the main method if that's all you're going to do in the main method?

Tags: java, multithreading, server

For example, if I'm doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

 Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyServerRunnable());
 myThread.start();

}
```

Am I better off to do this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

 MyServerClass server = new MyServerClass();
 server.start();

}
```

Where `start()` contains a while loop than handles everything.
Does it matter? With the first method, it feels like I'm starting a thread for no reason, since the main thread is literally just starting the other thread, I might as well use the main one instead.

Comment: I think the second one is more readable. On the other hand, it depends on how it affects your other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put it like this, the answer is yes. However it might be beneficial to have server implemented as Runnable, because later you might decide, that you want to use ThreadPool or another more advanced technique, and Runnable offers more flexibility with this.

Also, unless you call the Thread#join in the main, the main thread would finish after starting server, so you are not wasting that much actually.

Comment: Everything you say is true, but you don't need to create a thread in order to call the run() method of a Runnable object.

Answer (score 0):

if it's matter for you to have threads it does not really matter if you use main method to create threads. threads do share text segment and copy variables. you will get redundancy only if you have some vars in the main method only usable for one of the treads.